# Why did Laravel 5 remove Cascading Configs

Tags: php, laravel, config, laravel-5

Laravel 5 uses Dotenv library for environment specific configs that shouldn't be version controlled (eg: keys, secrets)

However, there could be applications that would use cascading configs for things that could be (should be) version controlled? (eg: db configs minus credentials, domains/URLS to associated services with their own dev/qa/prod setups,)

Given the above context, is that something I am missing as to why cascading configs are not useful. What was the reason for removal of cascading configs?

Comment: I wonder if this information would only be known inside the core development team, in which case it _might_ be better directed to the mailing list, or perhaps an IRC channel? It's quite "niche" knowledge, I would imagine.

Comment: I will try to post it up there. Meanwhile, I found this composer package https://github.com/phanan/cascading-config

Answer (score 1):

It was removed because it added unneeded complexity. array_merge_recursive being run for each config file was costly for things that could just be done in .env files.

The .env files also added the benefit of keeping that sort of config out of your SCM. Anything more complicated should really be thrown to a service provider.

Reference tweet about config decision: https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/551531700111822848